# Reason for using short leads with capacitor tester?

Tags: capacitor, testing, test-equipment, tester

When I was a high school freshman many moons ago, I took an electronics course. When the instructor introduced capacitors and how to test them, we used meters that had very short (3 inches or so long) leads. I remember that the instructor told us why such short leads were used but I don’t remember what the reason was.

Can anyone shine some light on this for me?

Comment: The leads add parasitic capacitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the leads will add additional capacitance. This will put the measurements in error. The lower the capacitance the bigger the effect.

Comment: So, if a capacitor is basically two conductors separated by an insulator, would that mean that PCB traces would have capacitance? Or other electronic components would have some (perhaps negligible) capacitance? Trying to wrap my head around the concept. Thanks.

Comment: You are only 100% spot on!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how small the cap is.  If less than 10 pF, it is more sensitive than 100 pF for stray capacitance.  So it is the pF/ cm of close couple wires that counts but not widely separated wires of typical RLC cables that does not matter. The better RLC meters have a null calibration regardless of length.

The wire pair might also add more negative capacitance (i.e. inductance @ ~ 800 pH/mm) than capacitance of << 1pF/mm.

But testing at 1MHz won't make much difference compared to at 1 GHz.

On a PCB with 10 mil track that is 20 mil over a ground plane it is 88 Ohms with 5.1 nH/cm and 0.65 pF/cm, then it is the relative change from the cable compared to the component being measured.

Again a null calibration is usually possible for any leads, but without that, as short as possible is safest.